# Angular + bootstrap - class radio-inline not working

Tags: angular, radio-button, alignment, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to use the `radio-inline` `bootstrap` class to have my radio buttons aligned on one line. My code is the following:

```
<label>Fattura a carico di </label>
          <label class="radio-inline control-label"><input type="radio" value="banca" name="fatturaCarico" [ngModel]="richiesta.fatturaCarico">Banca</label>
          <label class="radio-inline control-label"><input type="radio" value="cliente" name="fatturaCarico" [ngModel]="richiesta.fatturaCarico">Cliente</label>
```

And that's what I get:
[image]

Since this should be pretty straightforward, could it be `angular` that interferes with this in some way?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it removing `width:100%` on all input types. This was set by some css and made the radio occupy all the space causing the label falling on the next line. I added on my css

```
input[type=radio]{
  width: auto;
}
```

and worked.